# Pyschopy Visual stimuli position

Tags: python, psychopy, psychtoolbox

I'm having a problem with my text and radial stimuli in Psychopy.It seems like all of my text stim are shifted to the left. Despite the fact that the ($8, 0%) is given the same x coordinates as the radial stimuli they are consistently to the left of the radial stimuli and I'm not sure why[image]

```
Lot_a_win=visual.RadialStim(win=win,units="pix",name='Lot', color=col_code,opacity=1,
                      angularCycles = 0, radialCycles = 0, radialPhase = 0.5, colorSpace = 'rgb', 
                      ori= -90.0,pos=(lot_pos,0), size=(300,300),visibleWedge=(0.0, shade))

Lot_a_lose= visual.RadialStim( win=win, name='rad2', color=col_code,opacity=0.5,
                            angularCycles = 0, radialCycles = 0, radialPhase = 0.5, colorSpace = 'rgb', 
                            ori= 45.0, pos=(lot_pos,0), size=(300,300))
Lot_a_lose.draw()
Lot_a_win.draw()


SureMoney=visual.TextStim(win=win,text="$ %s"%(sure_m),pos=sure_pos,bold=True,units='pix')
SureMoney.draw()

Lot_per=visual.TextStim(win=win,text="%s %%"%(lot_p),pos=(lot_pos,-50),bold=True,units='pix')
Lot_Money=visual.TextStim(win=win,text="$ %s"%(lot_m),pos=(lot_pos,50),bold=True,units='pix')

Lot_per.draw()
Lot_Money.draw()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided working code (define `col_code`, `sure_m`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've got pyglet 1.4 installed and the text positioning system has changed. PsychoPy will support the changed system as best we can but, in the meantime I'd suggest you downgrade pyglet to 1.3.x

Comment: It would really help though if you spelled out what version of PsychoPy and what version of Pyglet you have installed

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot. I down graded pyglet and it fixed the problem.